Need to run the Recursive SQL query on PySpark or data farm for following scneri
This is an example in Development:


Equipment 1 has Equipment 3 as Parent.
Equipment 3 has Equipment 53 as Parent.
Equipment 53 has no Parent.
In the Gold Asset table, you will see following 3 records:

how to write the SQL Query in a optimize way
i have tried with Left Join so i got the parent Equipment  number but for top need to run the recursive query

Is the level of recursion always not more than 3?

Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]. Also see Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question? Currently there's nothing but some images of data, but with no effort shown.

Also: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

This answer is with the assumption that the level of recursion is 3. It is a bit of a clumbsy and elaborate way but it works. Hopefully someone out there provides an easier option.
I also tried using LEFT JOIN but ended up with the TOP fields of the root parent missing. So all we really need is a view which is the same as first table with an added column containing the TOP equipment number. Then when we do the LEFT JOIN we can get the TOP value for every other equipment number.
First create the sample tables
%sql
-- CREATE THE FIRST TABLE
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table1
(EQUINR STRING, HEQUI STRING);
INSERT INTO table1
VALUES ('0000001', '0000003'),
        ('0000003','0000053'),
        ('0000053', ''),
        ('0000002', '0000004'),
        ('0000004','0000054'),
        ('0000054', '');

-- CREATE THE SECONDARY TABLE
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table2
(EQUINR STRING, MATNR STRING, SERGE STRING);
INSERT INTO table2
VALUES ('0000001', '00010094', ''),
        ('0000003','00010097', '33'),
        ('0000053','00030053', '78941656'),
        ('0000002', '0001009X', ''),
        ('0000004','0001009X', '3X'),
        ('0000054','0003005X', '7894165X');

Now create temporary views from where we can get the TOP column for every equipment number
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW test_vw1 AS
SELECT b.EQUINR, b.HEQUI FROM table1 b where HEQUI IN (SELECT a.EQUINR FROM table1 a WHERE a.HEQUI = '');

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW test_vw2 AS
SELECT c.EQUINR, c.HEQUI, b.HEQUI AS TOP FROM table1 c LEFT JOIN test_vw1 b ON c.HEQUI = b.EQUINR 

Create additional views to fill in the gaps present in test_vw2
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW test_vw3 AS
SELECT * FROM test_vw2 WHERE HEQUI != '' AND TOP IS NOT NULL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW test_vw4 AS
SELECT EQUINR,HEQUI,TOP FROM test_vw2 WHERE HEQUI != '' AND TOP IS NULL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW test_vw5 AS
SELECT EQUINR,HEQUI,TOP FROM test_vw2 WHERE HEQUI = '' AND TOP IS NULL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW test_vw6 AS
(SELECT * FROM test_vw2 WHERE HEQUI != '' AND TOP IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT EQUINR,HEQUI,HEQUI AS TOP FROM test_vw4
UNION
SELECT EQUINR,HEQUI,EQUINR AS TOP FROM test_vw5); 

Now do your final select for all the data including the TOP equipment numbers.
%sql
SELECT A.*, B.HEQUI AS ParentEquipmentNumber, C.MATNR AS ParentMaterialCode, C.SERGE AS Parentmanuserialnumber, D.TOP AS TopEquipmentNumber, E.MATNR AS TopMaterialCode, E.SERGE AS Topmanuserialnumber FROM table2 A 
LEFT JOIN test_vw6 B ON B.EQUINR = A.EQUINR 
LEFT JOIN table2 C ON C.EQUINR = B.HEQUI 
LEFT JOIN test_vw6 D ON D.EQUINR = A.EQUINR    
LEFT JOIN table2 E ON E.EQUINR = D.TOP

You can refer to the full notebook.

Please note that the OP showed no work at all. They merely presented some requirements and (images of) a bit of data. The question itself, as written, is off-topic. What you wrote is a custom implementation, and doesn't actually answer any specific programming question - see Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question? Tl;dr please don't answer off-topic questions with custom solutions based on only a requirement and no actual work by the OP.

HI @anupam,
thanks for the good example.
but somehow it's not working.
here is my case
table 1
[
('000000000000000368', '000000000000000712'),
('000000000000000712',  '000000005490010954'),
('000000005490010954', Null)
]
Table 2
[
('000000000000000368', '000000000000102554', '14990015'),
('000000000000000712', '000000000000102552', '5400031739'),
('000000005490010954', 'KX633100','5490010954')
]
now output was
[('000000000000000368','000000000000102554','14990015','000000000000000712', '000000000000102552','5400031739','000000000000000712', '000000000000102552')]

But here now the TOP was logically 000000005490010954 but in the query it returned me the parent as top

@jestfresher - unformatted table content in a comment is unreadable. Comments are not for code. Feel free to edit your question. Aside from that: This answer really isn't related to anything you've done so far, as you haven't shown any work of your own, in your question. This isn't the place to post requirements and have people create solutions for you based on those requirements. In this case, someone  provided a solution anyway, and you're now asking them to further refine it.
